# Retrieve data from database when a link <a href.. > is clicked using only php and mysql or javascript(if necessary)

Tags: php, mysql

MY SIMPLE HTML TO PHP TEXT

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="description.php" id="1"><img src="images/ACER/aspire_vx15.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>  
    <a href="description.php" id="2"><img src="images/ACER/G9_593.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
    <a href="description.php" id="3"><img src="images/ACER/G9_793_75LA.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
    <a href="description.php" id="4"><img src="images/ACER/G9_793_76CH.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
    <a href="description.php" id="5"><img src="images/ACER/GX_792.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
    <a href="description.php" id="6"><img src="images/ASUS/FX753_VD.jpg" alt="ASUS"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**MY PHP CODE TO RETRIEVE DATA AGAINST THE ID OF EACH IMAGE IN DATABASE**

```
$host="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="mysite";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection Failed! ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    $id="";
    $sql="select * from products where id = $id";
    $query=mysqli_query( $conn,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $id      = $row['id'];
        $brand   = $row['brand'];
        $model   = $row['model'];
        $desc    = $row['description'];
        $img     = $row['image'];
        $price   = $row['price'];
        echo '<h3><a href="#">'.$brand.'   '.$model.'</a></h3><p>' .$img.''.$desc.'</p><p>Price: $'.$price.' '
        .'<input type ="button" value="Buy"></p></br>, ;
    }
}
?>
```

---

In my webpage I created the search field and was able to retrieve data from database by sending keywords by POST method, but I have been trying to give id to href and use that id to POST but its not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is pass the id as a parameter in query string to `description.php`

```
<a href="description.php?id=1" id="1"><img src="images/ACER/aspire_vx15.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>  
<a href="description.php?id=2" id="2"><img src="images/ACER/G9_593.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
<a href="description.php?id=3" id="3"><img src="images/ACER/G9_793_75LA.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
<a href="description.php?id=4" id="4"><img src="images/ACER/G9_793_76CH.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
<a href="description.php?id=5" id="5"><img src="images/ACER/GX_792.jpg" alt="Acer"></a>
<a href="description.php?id=6" id="6"><img src="images/ASUS/FX753_VD.jpg" alt="ASUS"></a>
```

The contents of `description.php`

```
$host="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="mysite";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection Failed! ".mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql="select * from products where id = $id";
} else {
    $sql="select * from products";
} 

$query=mysqli_query( $conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id      = $row['id'];
    $brand   = $row['brand'];
    $model   = $row['model'];
    $desc    = $row['description'];
    $img     = $row['image'];
    $price   = $row['price'];
    echo '<h3><a href="#">'.$brand.'   '.$model.'</a></h3><p>' .$img.''.$desc.'</p><p>Price: $'.$price.' '
    .'<input type ="button" value="Buy"></p></br>, ;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi. You just added an else statement which displays all the results.I want the row to be selected by id

Comment: Oh thanks for help. Sorry i didnt see the html file above.